# Laravel: Long database relationship chain in Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I am using Laravel for a project and making use of Eloquent for querying the database, but have ran into a problem with database structure and not sure how to improve it.

At the minute we have a company, which exists in many countries, each of which have many office locations, each with many staff.

When dealing with a member of staff, they have an office_ID, so to get their company you have to use the following chain:

Staff->Office->Country->Company.

This seems a bit overkill to do this every time, so would it be a bad idea to have a company_ID AND office_ID in the Staff table? Does this defeat the purpose of normalisation?